# Alamofire) i want processing always new request

Tags: ios, alamofire

head)
Hi, i’m making map application that show some information.

User can move map position by touch and application show some information.

When user touch finish, Application request information from REST API by locaiton. And this location can get from different API.

body)
When user move map long distnace, So many request occur. This situation make slow my application.

So i want to always make newer this request.

How can i request newer information in that too many request occur?

This is my request code.

I'm wating for your help.

code)

1. request location

```
private func doReverseGeocoding(lat: Double, lng: Double, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, Address?, String?) -> Void) {
    let id = HTTPHeader(name: "X-NCP-APIGW-API-KEY-ID", value:"sb10h4g44n")
    let key = HTTPHeader(name: "X-NCP-APIGW-API-KEY", value:"Czs7ZzPQHmgvPg0Y2cfMQEjxNg2WgOUB9LgS2uno")
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = HTTPHeaders([id, key])
    let urlString = "https://naveropenapi.apigw.ntruss.com/map-reversegeocode/v2/gc?request=coordsToaddr&coords=\(lng),\(lat)&sourcecrs=epsg:4326&output=json&orders=admcode,addr"

    guard let url = URL(string: generateURL(string: urlString)) else {
      return
    }

    AF.request(url, method: .get, headers: headers)
      .validate()
      .responseDecodable(of: NaverRoot.self) { (response) in
        guard let root = response.value else {
          completionHandler(false, nil, "[NAVER API] 리버스 지오코딩 정보를 불러올 수 없습니다. : \(response)")
          self.camera.setAddress(address: Address())
          return
        }

        if root.status.code == 3 {
          completionHandler(false, nil, "[NAVER API] 상세 주소 불러오기에 실패했습니다.")
          return
        }

        let region: Geo
        let landNumber: Land?

        if root.results.count == 2 {
          region = root.results[1].region
          landNumber = root.results[1].land
          self.currentAddress.setAddress(region: region, landNumber: landNumber)
        }
        else {
          region = root.results[0].region
          self.currentAddress.setAddress(region: region, landNumber: nil)

        }

        let address = self.camera.address

        if address.cityTown == self.currentAddress.cityTown {
          completionHandler(false, nil, nil)
        }
        else {
          self.camera.setAddress(address: self.currentAddress)
          completionHandler(true, self.currentAddress, "[NAVER API] 리버스 지오코딩 성공")
        }
    }
  }
```

2. request information

```
private func fetchStores(code locationCode: String,
                           address: String) {
    self.loadingIndicator.isHidden = false

    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

    let urlString = "https://openapi.gg.go.kr/RegionMnyFacltStus?KEY=\(KKD_APIKey)&TYPE=json&pSize=\(numberOfData)&REFINE_LOTNO_ADDR=\(address)"
    let url = generateURL(string: urlString)

    killAllRequest()

    AF.request(url)
      .validate()
      .responseDecodable(of: StoreRoot.self) { (response) in
        print("run time: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime)")
        guard let root = response.value else {
          print("[GG API]데이터를 불러올수 없습니다.: \(response)")
          print("[GG API]실패파라미터: \(address)")
          self.loadingIndicator.isHidden = true
          return
        }

        guard let head = root.RegionMnyFacltStus[0].head else {
          print("[GO API]요청 해더 디코딩에 실패했습니다.")
          return
        }

        guard let count = head[0].count else {
          print("[GG API]불러온 가맹점 카운팅에 실패했습니다.")
          return
        }

        guard let stores = root.RegionMnyFacltStus[1].row else {
          print("[GG API]가맹점 정보를 불러오는데 실패했습니다.")
          return
        }

        print("[GG API] \(address)지역에 대한 \(count)개의 가맹점 정보를 불러오는데 성공했습니다.")
        // 캐싱을 위한 저장.
        self.map.stores = stores
        self.loadingIndicator.isHidden = true

        // 마커 설정.
        self.setMarkers()

    }
  }
```

3. real called function

```
 private func findStoreFollowCameraCoord(location: CLLocation) {
    doReverseGeocoding(lat: location.coordinate.latitude, lng: location.coordinate.longitude) { (isSuccess, address, message) in
      guard let message = message else { return }
      print(message)

      if isSuccess {
        guard let address = address else { return }
        let currentCityCode = CityCode.shared.returnCityCode(city: address.city)
        self.fetchStores(code: currentCityCode, address: address.cityTown)
      }
      else {
        return
      }
    }
  }
```